# Google Sheets Query string to date

Tags: google-apps, google-sheets-query

I have a Google spreadsheet of several thousand rows of data. Column BC contains a date in a string format, YYYYMMDD.

I am using Google's query function to pull specific records from the main sheet into other tabs withing the same document, and as part of that query, I would like to reformat the date column to MM/DD/YYYY. I haven't yet found how to accomplish this.

Is there a simple way to reformat the string value inside of the query function, along the lines of a more traditional to_date(BC, 'MM/DD/YYYY')??

Example:
20170701  to  07/01/2017

Answer (score 0):

** EDITED **
Brian,

I assume you have already looked here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

The only way I really know is to convert the '20170701' format using text manipulation (CONCATENATE, RIGHT, MID, LEFT) to get the date in the proper format. Sorry, I didn't test this all the way through on my original post. It might be possible using the Query Language, but I haven't figured that out yet.